# Paypal REST API and custom checkout pages

Tags: rest, paypal, payment, checkout

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a custom checkout page when doing Paypal REST API payments?

So far, I've not found anything, but the REST API is ever-evolving, but unfortunately still lacks some key components.

Comment: Can you explain what customization you are looking for ?

Comment: I really just want to change the business name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the business name and the your company logo by creating the different "Experience Profiles" using REST API and passing the profile id in your Payment call . You can check the documentation here :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-web-experience-profile

Apart from that you can change the business name from your PayPal account maunally by going to this url after logging in :

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-business-info

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. The payment experiences work really well.